# Insert Rows Based on Cell Text Value and copy formula from below

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through 1 or more sheets with the aim to add a new row above if a specific text appears. On top of that, once the new row is entered, I want the formula from below to be copied over to the empty row. In theory my solutions below works.

However, the copied formulas from below are literarily the formulas from below, meaning the cell reference stayed the same - whereas I need the cell reference to update too:

currently:

=sum(E5:L5) in row below

copy to new empty row above - the code does:

=sum(E5:L5)

I'd want the code to do:

=sum(E4:L4)

```
Sub InsertRowsBasedonCellTextValue()
'Declare Variables
Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim new_inv As Range

Set new_inv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("all Investors").Range("L4")
'MsgBox new_inv

With Sheets("InvLevel_Test")
    'Define First and Last Rows
    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
        For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
            If .Range("C" & Row).Value = "Investor 8" Then
            
            .Range("C" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("C" & Row).Value = new_inv
            .Range("D" & Row & ":EY" & Row) = .Range("D" & Row - 1 & ":EY" & Row - 1).Formula
            
            End If
        Next Row
End With

End Sub
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to copy formulas with relative references is to use `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula`.

Just be aware that you should assign formulas to the property `Formula` resp. `FormulaR1C1` and not to `Value` as you do (implicitly) in your code:

```
.Range("D" & Row & ":EY" & Row).FormulaR1C1 = .Range("D" & Row - 1 & ":EY" & Row - 1).FormulaR1C1
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy formula by Copy/Paste instead of enter the formula text: '.Cells(3, 1).copy(.Cells(2, 1))'. It copies the value (formula) as well as the format which looks reasonable in your case.

Other staff:

1. Use 'Cells(rownumber, columnnumber)' instead of 'Range("C" & Row)': 'Cells(Row, 3)'
2. '.Range("D" & Row & ":EY" & Row)' --> '.Range(.Cells(Row, 4), .Cells(Row, 155))'
3. '.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row' --> '.UsedRange.Rows.Count'
4. '.Range("C" & Row).EntireRow.Insert' --> '.Rows(Row).Insert'

Explanation to use Cells instead of Range ([Range object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))):

*Although you can also use Range("A1") to return cell A1, there may be times when the Cells property is more convenient because you can use a variable for the row or column. The following example creates column and row headings on Sheet1. Be aware that after the worksheet has been activated, the Cells property can be used without an explicit sheet declaration (it returns a cell on the active sheet).*

*Note*

*Although you could use Visual Basic string functions to alter A1-style references, it is easier (and better programming practice) to use the Cells(1, 1) notation.*

Comment: (1) If you state that instead of using `Range` you should use `Cells`, you should explain why. All in all it's just a matter of taste. (2) Instead of 155, you can also write `.Cells(Row, "EY"))` which probably makes it more readable. (3) If you insist on using copy/paste but want only to copy the formulas (not formatting and the like), use `PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormulas)`